# R cleaning up a character and converting it into a numeric

Tags: r

R cleaning up a character string and converting it into a numeric

I have a character string

```
abc <-  "Â 267750Â"

class(abc)
"character"
```

What to I need to do to abc to get rid of "Â Â" and convert it from character to numeric.
Perhaps as.numeric will work but I need to get rid of "Â Â" first.

I want to convert the above to:

```
abc
267750
class(abc)
 "numeric"
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse out what you don't want with regular expressions:

```
test <- "532.dcx3vds98"
destring <- function(x,keep="0-9.") {
  return( as.numeric(gsub(paste("[^",keep,"]+",sep=""),"",x)) )
}
destring(test)
```

Returns `532.398`.

**Edit**

This is now in `taRifx`:

```
library(taRifx)
test <- "532.dcx3vds98"
destring(test)
```

Comment: Sure.  I'll probably add the function to the next version of `taRifx` so it's easier to use.  If anyone thinks of any clever features that need adding (or a better function name), please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

a little shorter using `stringr`:

```
    # load library
    library(stringr)
    # load data
    abc <-  "Â 267750Â"
    # extract digits
    abc <- as.numeric(str_extract(abc, "[0-9]+"))
    # check the result
    abc
    [1] 267750
    class(abc)
    [1] "numeric"
```